# Devolver parámetro C#

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de devolver un parametro para llenar un label en c#

```
 public void user_logueado(string msg)
    {

        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        MessageBox.Show(msg);
        frm.user_logueado_label.Text = msg;
    }
```

Y asi llamo el objeto:

```
jsObj s = new jsObj();
s.user_logueado("Usuario Logueado...");
```

Pero el label no se llena.

Comment: Sera porque no estas mostrando el formulario: `frm.Show()`?

Comment: que es jsObj? donde esta ubicado user_logueado? algo suena bizarro en el codigo. de paso mira [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Para que tu método devuelva un resultado, tienes que indicarlo al declarar el método. Tendrías que hacer lo siguiente:

Para que tu método devuelva un string:

```
public string user_logueado(string msg){...}
```

Para que devuelva un entero:

```
public int user_logueado(string msg){...}
```

Para que devuelva un listado de enteros:

```
public List<int> user_logueado(string msg){...}
```

En tu caso quieres que devuelva un string, deberías poner lo que he puesto en el primer punto, con lo cual, tu método quedaría:

```
public string user_logueado(string msg)
{

    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    MessageBox.Show(msg);
    frm.user_logueado_label.Text = msg;
}
```

Si haces esto, estás obligado a poner la cláusula return, que es donde le indicas lo que vas a devolver, si queremos devolver msg puedes hacer esto:

```
public string user_logueado(string msg){
    ...
    return msg;
}
```

Pero si lo que quieres hacer es pasar el texto a una etiqueta, lo puedes hacer de varias maneras:

1-

```
//Devolviendo void
public void user_logeado(string msg)
{
    //Haces lo necesario con el nombre (darle formato o alguna cosa)
    user_logeado_label.Text = msg;
}
```

2-

```
//Devolviendo string
public string user_logeado(string msg)
{
    //Haces lo necesario con el nombre (darle formato o alguna cosa)
    return msg;
}

//En el código donde llamas al método
user_logeado_label.Text = user_logeado(texto);
```

En tu código creas un formulario, no se si es porque el label está en otro formulario o en el mismo en el que declaras el método user_logeado (o esque ahí igual te has "colado"). Si el label está en el otro formulario, lo tendrías que hacer de otra manera.

Answer (score 0):

Para que un método devuelva un valor es necesario indicar un tipo, usted coloco void (vacio). Lo cual le indica a C# que no plenea devolver ningún resultado.

public **string** user_logueado(string msg)

En este caso le indica al lenguaje que devolvera un valor de tipo string.

Como consecuencia de colocar un tipo de varable devuelto le debe indicar como lo devolverá y para eso utiliza **return**

```
return frm.user_logueado_label.Text = msg;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! gracias por la respuesta, evita poner imagenes, pon mejor el codigo. y ese return es bastaste raro.. no se cual fue tu idea de lo que querias demostrar, pero alcanzaba con return msg (ya que con el form no haces nada y muere al salir de la funcion).

Comment: Voy a responder el comentario de @gbianchi porque le puede ser útil a quien pregunto la aclaración. Trate de demostrar como funcionan los métodos en C# para que devuelven valores. Hice las menores modificaciones para que fueran mas notorias. No cuestiono el otro código porque no tengo el contexto de lo que desea lograr y por eso me abstengo de juzgar aunque en principio estoy de acuerdo que parecen sobrar cosas allí.

Comment: Considero que esta respuesta es incorrecta. A pesar de que el OP habla de devolver parametro es evidente que lo que intenta hacer es que su método ponga el texto recibido en un label del formulario principal. Y el `return frm.user_logueado_label.Text = msg` es totalmente erróneo, solo por eso la respuesta no es correcta.